# Can I modify cmd.exe or PowerShell behavior so that tab autocomplete doesn't clear everything after the caret?

Tags: windows, command-line, autocomplete

In either Windows command prompt **cmd.exe** or the **PowerShell**, I can do tab completion for many things, such as cycling through commands, filenames, or directories. The problem is, it deletes everything after the cursor. So, if for example, I have two files I want to process, namely `bojot.mp4` and `donat.mp4`, which both reside in the same directory, let's say I start with the first one:

```
ffmpeg -i c:\tmp\vid\bojot.mp4 -an -sameq -s 640x480 bangang.mpg
```

So far so good. Now I just need to change the input file right? Press <kbd>↑</kbd> once, retrace to bojot.mp4 and delete it, type <kbd>d</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd>, just like in **bash**. But what I got is:

```
ffmpeg -i c:\tmp\vid\donat.mp4
```

What? Now I have to retype all the params and args! Can't I fix this?

Don't tell me Cygwin/MSys is the only way…

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for the last weeks where I really started using Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with CMD, but you can with [**TCC/LE**](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm), which is a free alternative command shell with a superset of features.

I have it as a tab within [**Console2**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), where I have defined standard keyboard shortcuts for Copy and Paste as well, to make life easier.

Comment: Hooray! A lightweight (it really starts up fast!) command console with just what I need! Except that you were a bit too late; I already installed Cygwin :( But thanks for pointing to Console2!
(I wonder why it defaults to insert mode at first)
(Note to self: preinstall TCC/LE on the next Windows box)

Comment: @syockit: You can also wrap Cygwin bash within Console2, in case you hadn't realised.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something lightweight that works within cmd, just install [Clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink/). Makes path completion work as if it wasn't implemented by a drunkard. Also completes executables and environment variables. Fixes some of cmd's other shortcomings as well.